# find the standard matrix for linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the standard matrix $T=T_2 \circ T_1$, where $$T_1:\Bbb{R}^3 \to \Bbb{R}^3, \qquad T_1(x,y,z)=(x+2y, y-z, -2x+y+2z)$$ and 
$$T_2:\Bbb{R}^3 \to \Bbb{R}^3, \qquad T_2(x,y,z)=(y+z,x+z, 2y-2z)$$

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Comment: i dont know where to begin from,,any hints

Comment: yes, my hint is read the stuff your professor told you about matrices and then try to solve the problem. There's no sense in us solving this problem for you if you don't even know where to begin.

Comment: You don't know anything at all about how to find the matrix representing a linear map like $T(x,y,z)=(x+2y,y-z,-2x+y+2z)$, shoaz?

Comment: yes, and i dont have any notes related to similar question

Comment: OK. What it means for the matrix $A$ to represent the transformation $T$ is that for every vector $v$ we have $T(v)=Av$. So, can you find a matrix $A$ such that if $v=(x,y,z)$ then $Av=(x+2y,y-z,-2x+y+2z)$?

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You seem to have formed the habit, shoaz, of asking questions and then disappearing. Please be a bit more responsive.

Comment: sorry, for late responding..thnx for hints,,i was able to solve this question

Comment: Good. Let me encourage you to write up your solution, and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The key is to find the matrices corresponding to these transformations and multiply them.  For example, $T_1$ is defined by
$$
T_1(x,y,z)=(x+2y+0z, 0x+y-z, -2x+y+2z)
$$
so, the matrix corresponding to $T_1$ will be
$$
A_1 = \pmatrix{1&2&0\\0&1&-1\\-2&1&2}
$$
Similarly, we may find the matrix $A_2$ corresponding to $T_2$.  In order to find the matrix for $T_2 \circ T_1$, compute the matrix product $A_2 A_1$.

Comment: If you don't have any notes on how to multiply matrices, I recommend looking [here](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-multiplying.html)